# Return a value from csv file by iterating over a 2D array in a specific manner

Tags: python, csv

I have an array and I want to get values from a csv file which match the elements of a given array. I have tried with the following code but it only checks for 1st element and exits loop. Can anyone help me out on how to iterate over all elements in the given array?
Thank you in advance.

Here is my code which I have tried.

```
import csv

location_file = csv.reader(open('Location.csv', "r"), delimiter=";")

test_array = [['16', '2'],['19', '2'],['16', '8'],['16', '9'],['16', '10'],['11', '2'],['11', '6'],['1', '12'],['1', '5'],['1', '4'],['4', '4'],['4', '6'],['14', '2'],['14', '7']]

for i in range (13):
    if i >= 0:
        for row in location_file:     
            if test_array[i][0] == row[2] and test_array[i][1] == row[3]:
                print(row[0])
```

Comment: what is the data inside and the `Location.csv` file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. In order to get help, you will need to provide additional information, like sample input file and desired output.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think your file iteration needs to be in the outer loop and the list iteration needs to be in the inner loop. Also, you can do `range(1, 13)` and omit your `if` if you aren't using an `else`.

Comment: @codester_09 Data inside Location.csv are coordinates and their location as name in a warehouse. I need to extract the location names exactly as coordinates in the thest_array.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I have tried file iteration with outside loop but the order is not correct

Comment: Your code sets `i` to zero then does nothing, then it sets `i` to one, then reads all the lines in the file and prints some of them then exits. When value of `i` is any other value, the `for row` loop gets EOF each time. If you want to do this even though some some other method would be much more efficient, you need to `seek(0)` the file for each iteration of the list. And you'll need to separate your `csv.reader` and `open` so you can seek the file rather than the reader.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, Thank you soo much for your suggestion. I tried your solutionn and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the file opening line:

```py
file = open('Location.csv', "r")
location_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
```

and add this before your second (inner) `for` statement:

```py
        file.seek(0)
```

This will reset to the beginning of the file for each iteration of the outer `for` loop.

Note that there are probably more efficient ways to do what you're trying to do. Rereading the same file multiple times may not be necessary.